# How to extract links from a page using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a [HTML Page](https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc) with multiple divs like:

```
<div class="post-info-wrap">
  <h2 class="post-title"><a href="https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-1st-post/" title="Example of 1st post &#8211; Example 1 Post" rel="bookmark">sample post &#8211; example 1 post</a></h2>
  <div class="post-meta clearfix">

    <div class="post-info-wrap">
      <h2 class="post-title"><a href="https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-2nd-post/" title="Example of 2nd post &#8211; Example 2 Post" rel="bookmark">sample post &#8211; example 2 post</a></h2>
      <div class="post-meta clearfix">
```

and I need to get the  value for all the divs with class post-info-wrap I am new to BeautifulSoup

so I need these urls:

- https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-1st-post/
- https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-2nd-post/
- and so on...

I have tried:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc") 
data = r.content  # Content of response

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for link in soup.select('.post-info-wrap'):
   print link.find('a').attrs['href']
```

This code doesnt seem to be working. I am new to beautiful soup. How can i extract the links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`link = i.find('a',href=True)` always not return `anchor tag (a)`, it may be return `NoneType`, so you need to validate link is None, continue for loop,else get link href value.

**Scrape link by url:**

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc")
data = r.content  # Content of response
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'post-info-wrap'}):
   link = i.find('a',href=True)
   if link is None:
       continue
   print(link['href'])
```

**Scrape link by HTML:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div class="post-info-wrap"><h2 class="post-title"><a href="https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-1st-post/" title="Example of 1st post &#8211; Example 1 Post" rel="bookmark">sample post &#8211; example 1 post</a></h2><div class="post-meta clearfix">
<div class="post-info-wrap"><h2 class="post-title"><a href="https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-2nd-post/" title="Example of 2nd post &#8211; Example 2 Post" rel="bookmark">sample post &#8211; example 2 post</a></h2><div class="post-meta clearfix">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'post-info-wrap'}):
   link = i.find('a',href=True)
   if link is None:
       continue
   print(link['href'])
```

**Update:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'post-info-wrap'}):
    link = i.find('a', href=True)
    if link is None:
        continue
    print(link['href'])
```

O/P:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/911/article-1/
https://www.example.com/blog/911/article-2/
https://www.example.com/blog/911/article-3/
https://www.example.com/blog/911/article-4/
https://www.example.com/blog/random-blog/article-5/
```

**For chrome browser:**

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**Install web driver for chrome browser:**

https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

**selenium tutorial**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Where `'/usr/bin/chromedriver'` chrome webdriver path.

Comment: @seeker2345  `https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc`  page div does not contain `.post-info-wrap` class.

Comment: @seeker2345 you should use valid website URL which is div contain .post-info-wrap class.

Comment: see the output of the page in the example.  I guess code is not working because you are forgetting that there is an <h2 class="post-title"> next to it before the href.

Comment: @seeker2345 you should try the second solution will get o/p like this 
https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-1st-post/
https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-2nd-post/

Comment: @seeker2345  your "https://www.getastra.com/blog/author/vikas/" URL dynamic rendering `(js or ajax)` request and you're are using simple requests module to get download website URL. requests module download only statics page data. you should use `selenium automation` library to scrap dynamic data.

Comment: thanks a ton man!. Can u tell what modifications would be done to the code to accomplish that?

Comment: thanks. Worked perfect!! . You are good at this stuff. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @seeker2345  Accept my answer if it resolved your problems.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `soup.find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
r = [i.a['href'] for i in soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'post-info-wrap'})]
```

Output:

```
['https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-1st-post/', 'https://www.example.com/blog/111/this-is-2nd-post/']
```

Comment: code not working. I guess this is because you are forgetting that there is an <h2 class="post-title"> next to it before the href.