# Python Replace Text beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I'm trying to replace specific text with beautiful soup :
My Code :

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

dorks = input("Keyword : ")

binglist = "http://www.bing.com/search?q="
    
with open(dorks , mode="r",encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        clean = binglist + line
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(clean, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
        links =  soup.find('cite')
        print(links)
```

Ouput :

```
[<cite>https://www.wsltv.com/tv-<strong>allinurl:-streaming</strong>/s17455</cite>, <cite>https://www.<strong>google</strong>.es/webhp</cite>]
```

So i'm trying to remove all

I have try this regex but i didn't successful to extract only the website site URL

Like this :

```py
links = soup.find_all('http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$')
```

But i didn't successful to extract only URL's.

Thanks for you're help

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421148/how-to-extract-links-from-a-page-using-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a list of web elements. To get just the text contents, you use the `.text` property.

```py
links = soup.find_all('cite')
for cite in links:
    print(cite.text)
```

Comment: Okay you're code fixed could you give me some explication please ? for i understand as well

Comment: You should learn to read the documentation of the packages you are using.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation